# Reading text file with latest time stamp in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, loops

I have a small program through which I am trying to read log files generated in a file location like below

```py
Error_Suspects = ['Error', 'ERROR', 'Failed', 'Failure']


def detect_suspects(file_path, word_list):
    with open(file_path) as LogFile:
        Summary = {word: [] for word in word_list}
        failure = ':'
        for num, line in enumerate(LogFile, start=1):
            for word in word_list:
                if word in line:
                    failure += '<li>' + line + '</li>'
    return failure


Result = detect_suspects(r'C:\scripts\Log.txt', Error_Suspects)
```

now the issue is this was good until I have only one single file. But now the files are generated at a certain interval with the timestamp as below.

[image]

I want to modify the above program in such a way so that it should always check the file with the latest time stamp. Also, I want to loop this program to run every 5 mins to check for the latest file. If new file doesn't arrive within 5 min it should not read the old one (which is already been read)

Comment: Please fix the inline image

Comment: Hi andras..I am very new and could not find a way to do that. But if you look on my updated questions ,I am not even looking at the text file names.I now just want to loop this every 5 sec.

Comment: Basically, you missed a `!` before the referred the image - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images

Comment: right u r..but it also need 10 reputation to post images..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in the directory containing all those files, you can use [`os.path.getmtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) to get the latest file.

You'd use it like this:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('.')
latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

`os.listdir` returns a list of all files in the current directory. `max` with the key finds the file with the most recent modification time, and returns it.

---

To loop over your directory every 5 minutes, you'll need to instate a `while` loop:

```
import time
while True:
    Result = detect_suspects(r'C:\scripts\Log.txt', Error_Suspects)
    time.sleep(5 * 60) # 300 seconds or 5 minutes
```

Comment: Wao!! Thanks for replying so fast...the code did work... I am very new to python..can you help me modifying the code to loop this program to run every 5 sec to check the latest file .

Comment: @COLDSPEED I have updated my original question with the code.Can you please have a look...if you don't mind

Comment: @AniruddhyaDutta I'd love to help. But changing the theme of a question constantly is bad form as it reduces its readability for future readers. I urge you to open another one.

Comment: @COLDSPEED unfortunately I can post only every 90 miniutes it seems.Can you please help me as of now..I will post once I get some chance again..

Comment: Okay... you'll put a while loop, call your function, and sleep for 5 seconds. `import time; while True: Result = detect_suspects(r'C:\scripts\Log.txt', Error_Suspects); time.sleep(5)`

Comment: @COLDSPEED can you please look into my edit 2 in the question. When I run its constantly returning the program name in the console..

Comment: @AniruddhyaDutta You've implemented it wrong. The fix is simple but a comment is too short to do justice to it ;/

Comment: @COLDSPEED can I get your mail id by any chance? if only its not too much I am asking..

Comment: @AniruddhyaDutta My email is in my profile but I don't answer questions offline. :)

Comment: I get you..but I have wait again till I post a new question where you can answer...is it like someone cant post an improvement once its got accepted..?

Comment: @AniruddhyaDutta Not sure... I haven't been in this position before. Try now?

Comment: I think you can edit and improve your original answer..I see there is an option to edit @COLDSPEED

Comment: @AniruddhyaDutta Editing my answer is fine, but like I said, you shouldn't pollute a question once it has been closed. Just wait a few more minutes!

Comment: @AniruddhyaDutta Also recommend when you can, rollback your edit so as to leave out details that don't concern themselves with this question.

Comment: I totally agree with you..but this looping thing was also mentioned in my original question..so if you just take it as an exception today...:( it seems like I am in the brink of getting this resolved ..its only that I have to wait to post a new question...@coldspeed

Comment: @COLDSPEED...Thanks a lot...what a silly mistake I was making..but as promised I have posted a new question...can you look into that whenever you get some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232362/need-improvement-in-the-while-loop-in-python-program